# rate of change in natural log $\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have confusion with the rate of change in natural logarithm, as we know that,

in analytical manner

> \begin{gather*} y\ =\ \ln( x)\\ \\ \frac{dy}{dx} \ =\ \frac{1}{x}\\
> \end{gather*}

or in a numerical manner

> \begin{equation*} \text{rate of change}=\frac{ln( x) \ -\ ln( x-n)}{x\ -\ (
>  x-n)} , \text{ where } n =\text{no. of steps which takens} \end{equation*}

but output of both of them differs why? while both formulas used to find rate of change.

like:

\begin{gather*}
x\ =\ 7\\
\frac{dy}{dx} \ =\ \frac{1}{x} \ =\ 0.14285714285\\
\\
-\ or\ -\\
=\frac{ln( x) \ -\ ln( x-n)}{x\ -\ ( x-n)} \ \\
=\ \frac{ln( 7) \ -\ ln( 7-1)}{7\ -\ ( 7-1)} \ \\
=\ ln( 7) \ -\ ln( 6) \ \\
=\ 0.15415067982
\end{gather*}

why there is such a difference?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The derivative is the limit as the "step" size goes to $0$

Comment: Your numerical formula is wrong

Comment: It may be 1/n rather than n . Check it out

Comment: Also derivative is limit as n approaches $\infty$ (n becomes larger ). Your numerical formula provides good approximation

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @J. W. Tanner's answer, this is the result of reducing the "step" size

```
        n  rate of change  derivative
 1.000000        0.154151    0.142857
 0.193070        0.144864    0.142857
 0.037276        0.143239    0.142857
 0.007197        0.142931    0.142857
 0.001389        0.142871    0.142857
 0.000268        0.142860    0.142857
 0.000052        0.142858    0.142857
 0.000010        0.142857    0.142857
```

This is all taking $x = 7$. As you can readily see, the smaller the step the closer to the actual value of the derivative. They both match when $n \to 0$